# Fabric: Send Crashlytics Key with crash

Tags: android, crash-reports, google-fabric

I am using Fabric in my Android App. I want to send a crash timestamp as soon crash occurs. I am able to send crash key before crash arises, but crash key was not getting sent after crash arises.

I was trying to send crash key from UncaughtExceptionHandler but crash key is not sent. I am suspecting that Fabric is sending crash keys before UncaughtExceptionHandler's uncaughtException method gets executed.

Comment: Key as your API key to be able to use crashlytics? Why would you send that? And if you need to send it, can't you just create your own sender?(not really familiar with crashlytics, so I don't know if you can create your own senders)

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. The specific crash or error will already have the timestamp included so you don't need to set this manually.

Comment: I need to send time stamp or any other unique key, so that I can search in crashlytics portal for crash logs using that Key. This is a requirement in my case. If UncaughtExceptionHandler cant be used to send crash key then do we have any listener in crashlytics sdk or any class by overriding which, we can send crash key? I have to show this crash key in my app when next time user logs in and I can use this key to search crash logs from crashlytics portal based on this. Please let me know a way for doing it

Comment: Gotcha, custom keys can't be written to Fabric post crash, but you could write this data to your own service. I'd recommend writing it pre-crash when possible, but if you must do it post-crash. In this case, you would need to configure your own UncaughtExceptionHandler and send the data to your own service.

Comment: Mike, it will not serve my purpose. As I need to send this key to Crashlytics also for searching purpose (post crash) and via this approach I will only end up with this key on only my App .